# How does strlen() value automatically changes?

Tags: c, string, strlen

I wrote this code -

```
char s1[10] = "he",  s2[20] = "she", s3[30], s4[30];

printf("%d %d", strlen(s2) + strlen(s3), strlen(s4));
```

output -

```
6 9
```

Then I wrote this code -

```
char s1[10] = "he",  s2[20] = "she", s3[30], s4[30];

printf("%d %d", strlen(s3), strlen(s4));
```

by removing `strlen(s1) +`

output -

```
0 3
```

My question in how the length of string s4 changes ?

Comment: `s3` and `s4` are uninitialized, so probably undefined behaviour.

Comment: In the first example, `s4` is uninitialized, so `strlen(s4)` can be anything.  Indeed, the same goes for `strlen(s3)` since `s3` is uninitialized.  It does depend a bit on where the variables are defined.  If they're global, they will be initialized, but if they're local to a function, they will not.

Answer (score 2):

`s3` and `s4` are not initialized and are not `'\0'` terminated C-strings, which is what `strlen()` expects. So you can't pass them to `strlen()`.

What you see is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Well I read this in a book, in which it was asked  what would be the result of first code ? then I tried to remove ` strlen(s2) +` and I found this ambiguity .

Comment: May be, the book had initialized or assigned values to `s3` and `s4` later but before using `strlen()` or had them as global variables? If not, the book is wrong on this.

Comment: Consider changing your textbook and use a better one. Here's [SO's list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

You say "string s4", but `s4` does not contain a string. It's an array of characters with no particular contents. You can only perform a `strlen` on a C-style string. So your code is just broken. Its behavior will be unpredictable.

Comment: Well I read this in a book, in which it was asked  what would be the result of first code ? then I tried to remove ` strlen(s2) +` and I found this ambiguity .

Comment: @AkhilRaj The answer is that the code is broken and there's no way to predict the result. With deep understanding of one particular implementation (library, compiler, OS) you may be able to predict what happens on that particular platform, but the C++ specification just says that anything can happen. (I'm guessing that the difference you observed has to do with the change in stack alignment.)